# MapReduce client retrying to connect after job completion

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Running on Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 and issuing a simple Pig script.
After a successful job completion I'm getting the following message :

Seems like the workers are trying to communicate with each other (with a maximum of 3 retries) but I'm not sure why, and where this behavior is configured.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

```
Output(s):
Successfully stored 46933 records (12822705 bytes) in: "/profile/main_output_merged"

Counters:
Total records written : 46933
Total bytes written : 12822705
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1469941650260_0002  ->      job_1469941650260_0011,
job_1469941650260_0003  ->      job_1469941650260_0011,
job_1469941650260_0001  ->      job_1469941650260_0005,job_1469941650260_0006,
job_1469941650260_0005  ->      job_1469941650260_0006,
job_1469941650260_0006  ->      job_1469941650260_0007,
job_1469941650260_0007  ->      job_1469941650260_0008,job_1469941650260_0009,
job_1469941650260_0004  ->      job_1469941650260_0008,
job_1469941650260_0008  ->      job_1469941650260_0010,
job_1469941650260_0010  ->      job_1469941650260_0011,
job_1469941650260_0009  ->      job_1469941650260_0011,
job_1469941650260_0011


2016-07-31 05:28:54,418 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.22:38762. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:55,419 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.22:38762. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:56,420 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.22:38762. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:56,527 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:28:57,626 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:35325. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:58,628 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:35325. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:59,629 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:35325. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:28:59,732 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:00,833 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:45573. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:01,834 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:45573. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:02,835 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:45573. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:02,939 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:04,051 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:36934. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:05,052 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:36934. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:06,053 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:36934. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:06,157 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:07,244 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:43862. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:08,245 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:43862. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:09,246 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.24:43862. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:09,350 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:10,643 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:38481. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:11,644 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:38481. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:12,645 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:38481. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:12,749 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:13,832 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:34431. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:14,833 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:34431. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:15,834 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker-p2.c.project.internal/10.240.0.17:34431. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:15,937 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:17,045 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.27:38757. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:18,046 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.27:38757. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:19,047 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker1.c.project.internal/10.240.0.27:38757. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:19,149 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:20,230 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:37952. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:21,231 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:37952. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:22,232 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cdh-worker3.c.project.internal/10.240.0.25:37952. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-31 05:29:22,335 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-31 05:29:22,417 [MainThread] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

Comment: It can be related to this issue :- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4164.

Comment: Hi, seems that way, I got very similar errors. 
So now I've upgraded Pig to 0.15.0 and still getting those errors